# Alternative routes to entering the US without Marriage

Tags: usa, immigration, canada

as a little background I'm a Canadian wanting to enter the US to spend more time with my love and have been engaged in a relationship for over the past 3 years.

We're both very hesitant to get up and get married just for me to spend more time with her and would much prefer for it to happen when the time is right. What are our other alternative options?

To be clear, I am not necessarily asking routes to being a citizen but would like more time to spend in the US.

Thank-you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Canada is rare in that it explicitly permits people visiting as tourists to work remotely for their foreign employers, which you might want to consider if your partner can work remotely.  But that doesn't address your question.

The usual approach in cases like yours is to find a way of entering the US independent of your relationship.  Depending on age, most people seek either a student visa or as a work visa, but if you are entrepreneurial (and especially if you are wealthy) you could also set up a business to help you move to the US.

Canadians have had a somewhat easier time moving to the US if they are employable in one of the NAFTA specialty occupations, but I do not know whether that will persist given the current administration's antipathy to NAFTA.

Without knowing the state of your career, it's hard to say anything more specific than this.